# ST_AsMvt - ERROR: Missing libprotobuf-c

Tags: postgis, installation, ubuntu

I have updated PostGIS to 2.4.3. Using with Postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 14. When I try to `select ST_AsMvt(example_geometry) from example_table`, I get:

```
 ERROR:  Missing libprotobuf-c
 ********** Error **********

 ERROR: Missing libprotobuf-c 
 SQL state: XX000
```

As it it mentioned on [PostGIS Installation](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html):

> To enable ST_AsMVT protobuf-c library (for usage) and the protoc-c
>   compiler (for building) are required. Also, pkg-config is required to
>   verify the correct minimum version of protobuf-c.

If I execute `protoc --version`, I get `libprotoc 3.5.0`.

`libprotobuf-c0`, `libprotobuf-c0-dev`, `libprotobuf-dev` are already installed.

Tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall postgis` but didn't help.

Related issues:

- [ST_AsMVT Centos 7 Missing libprotobuf-c](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/postgis-users/SAH9MDwq2io)
- [Postgis ST_AsMVT() return missing libprotobuf-c on MacOSX High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629891/postgis-st-asmvt-return-missing-libprotobuf-c-on-macosx-high-sierra)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can solve this problem by installing libprotobuf-c on the system.

Comment: It seems that it's installed but ST_AsMvt still not work.

Comment: @Justas Do you have also `libprotobuf-c-dev` installed?

Comment: No. I have installed libprotobuf-c0-dev

Comment: When I try to install libprotobuf-c-dev, I get E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c-dev

Comment: In the moment I'm not able to check this with Linux. When you type  `libprotobuf`in the terminal and hit `tab` twice there should be the right package. I think it's the `libprotobuf-c0-dev` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdevel/libprotobuf-c0-dev, same you've wrote above). Installing this package could solve the problem. I'm not sure if you have to reboot or reconnect the PostgreSQL server.

Comment: I have restarted Postgres service. I have 9.3, 9.6, 10 Postgres versions, wondering if it may affect something.

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS needs to be compiled with protobuf support. If not compiled with protobuf support, you will get error message: `error: Missing libprotobuf-c`

Steps to compile PostGIS with protobuf support:

```
#install from repository (if possible)
apt-get install protobuf-c-compiler

#install protobuf (only if protobuf-c-compiler from repository is 
#not working or available)
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
cd protobuf
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig 

# install protobuf-c (only if protobuf-c-compiler from repository is
# not working or available):
cd ~/
curl -OL https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-/releases/download/v1.3.2/protobuf-c-1.3.2.tar.gz
    cd protobuf-c-1.3.2
./configure && make
sudo make install

#install correct postgres-server-dev-xx version
apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-xx

#download postgis source code from https://postgis.net/source/
tar xvf postgis-x.x.x.tar.gz
cd postgis-x.x.x
./autogen.sh
#if you have multiple postgres versions installed,
#use --with-pgconfig option below, replace xxx with your version
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/lib/postgresql/xxx/bin/pg_config
#check output of the ./configure commmand if protobuf is supported
#and if building for correct postgres version
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct solution to this problem. I'm in the same boat as the person who asked the question.

As a workaround, I have found using this Docker Image in place of my local DB to work. https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/